# Splitting field of $x^ {a^n}$ −1 in Z/aZ[x]

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

What is the splitting field of the polynomial $x^ {a^n}$ −1 in \ the ring Z/aZ[x] with n natural?

I´m working in some kind of proof of the best known theorem that says it´s impossible there exist a finite algebraic field, and in this way, I found this question

(First of all, the a must be prime for it have sense to be Z/aZ[x] field)

Comment: A *finite algebraically closed field*, probably. And maybe the polynomial should be $x^{a^n}-x$, as the polynomial you mention splits over $\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z}$ (with $a$ prime, of course), as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you observed, for $\Bbb{Z}/a\Bbb{Z}$ to be a field, it is necessary and sufficient that $a$ is a prime number. But in that case, by the so called Freshman's Dream:
$$x^{a^n}-1=(x-1)^{a^n}.$$ This means that the splitting  is the field $\Bbb{Z}/a\Bbb{Z}$ as $x=1$ is the only zero (with multiplicity $a^n$), so your polynomial splits into linear factors over the prime field.

Comment: But what was the question you really wanted to ask?